# Dictionary enumeration in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, enumeration

How do I enumerate a dictionary?

Suppose I use `foreach()` for dictionay enumeration. I can't update a key/value pair inside `foreach()`. So I want some other method.

Answer (score 94):

To enumerate a dictionary you either enumerate the values within it:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dic;

foreach(string s in dic.Values)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

or the KeyValuePairs

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in dic)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Key : " + kvp.Key.ToString() + ", Value : " + kvp.Value);
}
```

or the keys

```
foreach(int key in dic.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
}
```

If you wish to update the items within the dictionary you need to do so slightly differently, because you can't update the instance while enumerating. What you'll need to do is enumerate a different collection that isn't being updated, like so:

```
Dictionary<int, string> newValues = new Dictionary<int, string>() { 1, "Test" };
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in newValues)
{
   dic[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value; // will automatically add the item if it's not there
}
```

To remove items, do so in a similar way, enumerating the collection of items we want to remove rather than the dictionary itself.

```
List<int> keys = new List<int>() { 1, 3 };
foreach(int key in keys)
{
   dic.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Or you can enumerate the keys.

Comment: I'd expect that enumerating the keys would be more common than enumerating only the values (at least it has been in my experience), since you can find the value for the key quite easily (that being the point of the dictionary).

Comment: This covers the enumeration but not the update. To update, you'll need to use one of the methods below... see spender's answer.

Answer (score 9):

In answer to the problem "I can't update value/key inside foreach()", you cannot modify a collection while enumerating it. I would approach this by making a copy of the Keys collection:

```
Dictionary<int,int> dic=new Dictionary<int, int>();

//...fill the dictionary

int[] keys = dic.Keys.ToArray();
foreach (int i in keys)
{
    dic.Remove(i);
}
```

Comment: No need for .ToArray() AFAIK.  .Keys returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: sure, but if the dictionary is altered in the loop, what happens to that enumeration? it changes, surely?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. The dic.Keys will return an IEnumerable<int> in this case, which will be all values. If you were to just use the IEnumerator<int> instead then this might be the case.

Comment: changing the line:
    foreach(int i in keys)
to
    foreach(int i in dic.keys)
throws and InvalidOperationException, "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
Making a copy, as above does not fail in this way.

Comment: You can still do it inline, just add .ToArray()... so foreach(int i in dic.Keys.ToArray())

Comment: Sure, you can do it inline, but it's the same thing at the end of the day. In the optimized release binary, it probably gets inlined anyway. On separate lines, it's easier to debug if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Foreach. There are three ways: You can enumerate over the `Keys` property, over the `Values` property or over the dictionary itself which is an enumerator of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 2):

I just answered the same (updated) question for lists, so here's the same thing for dictionaries.

```
public static void MutateEach(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Func<TKey, TValue, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> mutator)
{
    var removals = new List<TKey>();
    var additions = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();

    foreach (var pair in dict)
    {
        var newPair = mutator(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        if ((newPair.Key != pair.Key) || (newPair.Value != pair.Value))
        {
            removals.Add(pair.Key);
            additions.Add(newPair);
        }
    }

    foreach (var removal in removals)
        dict.Remove(removal);

    foreach (var addition in additions)
        dict.Add(addition.Key, addition.Value);
}
```

Note that we have to do the updates outside the loop, so we aren't modifying the dictionary as we enumerate it. Also this detects clashes caused by making two keys the same - it will throw (due to the use of `Add`).

Example - make all keys lowercase and trim all values, with a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
myDict.MutateEach(key => key.ToLower(), value => value.Trim());
```

If the keys are not unique when made lowercase, this will throw.